# map::insert is breaking

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

My map::insert method is breaking, without giving me a lot of useful information.

```
typedef map<wstring, int> IndexLookupMap;
static IndexLookupMap indexLookup;
static vector<LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9> textures;

extern "C" void EXPORT_API LoadTexture(const wchar_t* file, int* index, unsigned char* data) {

    wstring key(file);

    if(indexLookup.size() > 0)
    {
        IndexLookupMap::iterator it = indexLookup.find(key);

        if(it == indexLookup.end())
        {
            //not found, load it
            LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 pTexture;
            D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(g_D3D9Device, file, &pTexture);
            textures.push_back(pTexture);
            *index = textures.size() - 1;
            D3DLOCKED_RECT locked;
            pTexture->LockRect(0, &locked, NULL, 0);

            data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(locked.pBits);

            pTexture->UnlockRect(0);

            indexLookup.insert(IndexLookupMap::value_type(key, *index));
        }
        else
        {
            //found, get it
            *index = it->second;
            textures.at(*index);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //not found, load it
        LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 pTexture;
        D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(g_D3D9Device, file, &pTexture);
        textures.push_back(pTexture);
        *index = textures.size() - 1;
        D3DLOCKED_RECT locked;
        pTexture->LockRect(0, &locked, NULL, 0);

        data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(locked.pBits);

        pTexture->UnlockRect(0);

        indexLookup.insert(IndexLookupMap::value_type(key, *index)); //breaks here
    }
}
```

It is breaking on:

```
indexLookup.insert(IndexLookupMap::value_type(key, *index));
```

The actual break occurs in xtree:

```
_Nodeptr _Trynode = _Root();
```

Comment: What does "it is breaking" mean?

Comment: I'm running this as a plugin from inside Unity3D, breaking means: program crashes/exits.

Comment: @StormKiernan: Please do some debugging first to isolate the problem before posting your code on SO.

Comment: I already did. I gave you the exact line it breaks on. If I had more information, I'd give it. It is not breaking on any of my lines of code, it is breaking inside of STL code, and providing no useful errors.

Comment: To repeat James' question: what does "breaking" mean? Runtime error? Compile time error? What error, specifically? You're having trouble debugging it because you're not getting "a lot of useful information", but you're giving us even less.

Comment: It was an access violation error thrown at runtime in the middle of STL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the minimal information provided I suspect that `LoadTexture` is being called before your `map` is constructed, causing it to be in an invalid state.